# How to import a csv file in sqlite (within C)

Tags: c, sqlite

How would I do the the following in SQLite:

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, ".mode csv", NULL, NULL, &error_msg);
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "import MyFile.csv MyTable", NULL, NULL, &error_msg);
```

When I do the above, I get the following error:

> SQL error: near "import": syntax error

Here are the docs for doing a [csv import](https://sqlite.org/cli.html).

If this can't be done from within `sqlite3_exec`, how could I do this? Would there be a way to pipe the command to the shell from within c?

Comment: `.import` is specific to the sqlite3 shell, like all .-commands.

Comment: Use a csv parsing library (or write your own) and insert rows via a prepared statement.

Comment: You could also do something with the [csv virtual table module](https://www.sqlite.org/csv.html) and `create table foo as select ...` or `insert into foo select ...`